Issue with FileProvider in Android Unit test specific to Windows OS
My primary work machines are MacOs and ArchLinux, but sometimes I have to work on Windows as well.
First time I notices that there is difference in paths representations due to usage of \ and /. I guess it is easy to fix by using File.separator. Annoying solution but it works.
However I have this issue with my provider. It looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="photos" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="pdfs" path="." />
</paths>

It works fine on MacOs and ArchLinux, but on windows I get this error:
Failed to find configured root that contains C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Temp\robolectric-CameraFileHandlerLegacyTest_providedUriShouldBeForApplicationPackage1487572707286514179\external-files\Android\data\com.my.app.debug\Camera\20240624_1649111606355212673536148.jpg
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Temp\robolectric-CameraFileHandlerLegacyTest_providedUriShouldBeForApplicationPackage1487572707286514179\external-files\Android\data\com.my.app.debug\Camera\20240624_1649111606355212673536148.jpg
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:867)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:467)

This is my test:
 @Test
    fun providedUriShouldBeForApplicationPackage() {
        val handler = CameraFileHandler(
            context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context,
        )
        val given = handler.createTempPhotoFile()

        val actual = handler.provideExternalUri(given)

        actual.scheme shouldBe "content"
        actual.host shouldBe "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider"
    }

and my class is this:
@Singleton
class CameraFileHandler @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
) {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun createTempPhotoFile(): File {
        val storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(ExternalCameraDirectory)
        val timestamp = Clock.System.now()
        return File.createTempFile(timestamp.formatPhotoDate(), PhotoFileExtension, storageDir)
    }

    fun provideExternalUri(file: File): Uri =
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider", file)

    private fun Instant.formatPhotoDate() = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PhotoDateFormat)
        .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .format(toJavaInstant())

    companion object {
        @VisibleForTesting
        const val ExternalCameraDirectory = "Camera"
        private const val PhotoDateFormat = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"

        @VisibleForTesting
        const val PhotoFileExtension = ".jpg"
    }
}


It feels like File.createTempFile() is using the Windows temp directory, ignoring storageDir at least in part. Do you need File.createTempFile()?

@CommonsWare thanks for answering. Yeah, I need a temp file to store a picture that I am taking with camera.

You need a file to store a picture. That does not necessitate using File.createTempFile(). For example, you could use a UUID as the filename and guarantee uniqueness that way. So... are you sure that you need File.createTempFile()?
